# React - Dynamically load a component into the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I have a static component called Item.js

**Routes.js**

```
export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/posts" component={Posts} />
        <Route path="/form" component={Postform} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/items" component={Items} />
        <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
        <Route path="/page/:id" component={Page} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

In the above page component, I want to load item.js or any other page depending on whats passed to the URL params in as "id" in the page component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Item from './pages/Item';

class Page extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    console.log(id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div>Hello</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```

How do I achieve this? I don't know.

Are there any alternative ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Item from './pages/Item';

const components = [{
  id: 'your/id/passed/in/param'
  component: Item
}]

class Page extends React.Component {

  state = {
    Component: null,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.setState({ Component: components.find(comp => comp.id === id).component })
  }

  render() {
    const { Component } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Component /> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: What is 'your/id/passed/in/param'? Should I pass this.props.match.params there?

Comment: that is the :id corresponding to your component.

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice to put a component or complex objects in React state. The component is a huge object with circular references to your whole app. This can dramatically decrease performance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved it by following a variation of Johnny Peter's answer.

Page.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import components from './indexPage'


  class Page extends Component {

     render() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const PageComponent = components.find(comp => comp.id === id).component;

    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <PageComponent/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Page;
```

indexPage.js

```
import Item from './pages/Item'
import Meow from './pages/Meow'

const components = [{
    id: 'item',
    component: Item
  },
  {
    id: 'meow',
    component: Meow
  }
]

export default components;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index file like so:

index.js:

```
import Item from './item';

const pages = {
  pageId: Item,
};

export default pages;
```

And in page component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Item from './pages/Item';
import pages from './pages';

class Page extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    console.log(id);
  }

  render() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    if (pages[id]) {
      return pages[id];
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div>Hello</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Page;
```

in order to dynamically load component based on id.

Comment: @Piyush Zalani Your example is not working, There are two syntax errors in it. You should test and run your example code before submitting your answer.